# fb login with codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: the return url should be registered into your fb account.

Comment: how can register the redirect url ???

Comment: go to `clients auth settings`  under `valid oauth redirect URI`